# Unexpected behavior using ViewPager with TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Hello everybody

I have a Fragment with a TabLayout with to tabs, I implement the PagerAdapter and everything work fine, the problem is when I go to other option and after that I tap in to the option again the TabLayout appears but empty, I will share with you the code that I wrote for this functionality:

Adapter:

```
public class DevicePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public DevicePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:{
                return new fragmentDeviceCategory();
            }
            case 1:{
                return new fragmentDeviceRoom();
            }
            default:{
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Code for one of the Fragments in the TabLayout:

```
 public class fragmentDeviceList extends Fragment {

    protected ViewPager viewPager;

    public fragmentDeviceList() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_devices_list));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_device_list, container, false);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.title_tab_by_category)).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_category_black_36dp, getActivity().getTheme())));
        } else {
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.title_tab_by_category)).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_category_black_36dp)));
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.title_tab_by_room)).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_room_black_36dp, getActivity().getTheme())));
        } else {
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.title_tab_by_room)).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_room_black_36dp)));
        }
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        DevicePagerAdapter adapter = new DevicePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

An this is the code that I'm using in the main Fragment who is hosting the TabLayout:

```
  public class fragmentDeviceList extends Fragment {

    protected ViewPager viewPager;

    public fragmentDeviceList() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_devices_list));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_device_list, container, false);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.title_tab_by_category)).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_category_black_36dp, getActivity().getTheme())));
        } else {
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.title_tab_by_category)).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_category_black_36dp)));
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.title_tab_by_room)).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_room_black_36dp, getActivity().getTheme())));
        } else {
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.title_tab_by_room)).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_room_black_36dp)));
        }
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        DevicePagerAdapter adapter = new DevicePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Note: When I debugged the code I note that the method `onCreateView` in the `fragmentDeviceList` (The fragment that it is hosted the TabLayout) it is executed, but the method `onCreateView` of the fragment `fragmentDeviceCategory` is not fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the tabs inside a `Fragment` you should use `ChildFragmentManager`.

The line:

```
DevicePagerAdapter adapter = new DevicePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
```

should be:

```
DevicePagerAdapter adapter = new DevicePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

`FragmentPagerAdapter` is a valid use for just two fragments because it keeps them in memory. `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is intended for a larger number of fragments.

Also `TabLayout` has a method `setupWithViewPager` that will:
This method will:

- Add a ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener that will forward events to this TabLayout.
- Populate the TabLayout's tabs from the ViewPager's PagerAdapter.
- Set our TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener which will forward selected events to the ViewPager

You can use it instead of manually adding tabs.

Comment: @JoseRaulPerera also see my edit about setupWithViewPager

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for the problem, the solutions is very simple, I thought that I can use as Adapter for the ViewPage **FragmentPagerAdapter** because i want to show just fragments, but this class remain the state of the fragment so the nested fragment don't is initialized again, so I changed my adapter to **FragmentStatePagerAdapter** and now is working properly.

Thank you all